# store and fetch Array of Dictionary in CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm working on CoreData with swift , in my project I want to store/fetch dictionary in CoreData. My Dictionary contains Category details as well as SubCategories details(in Array of Dictionary form). I have taken model for category details but I'm not getting how to store subcategories details for perticular Category.

Should I take seperate model for subcategory?

So please help me to do this.

I have dictionary which looks like:

```
{
    "category": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "category_name": "Water",
      "sub_category_count": "3",
      "sub_category": [
       {
          "sub_categoryid": "1",
          "sub_categoryname": "Water1"
       },
       {
          "sub_categoryid": "2" ,
          "sub_categoryname": "Water2"
       },
       {
          "sub_categoryid": "3" ,
          "sub_categoryname": "Water3"
       }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "category_name": "Health",
      "sub_category_count": "3",
      "sub_category": [
      {
         "sub_categoryid": "1" ,
         "sub_categoryname": "Health1"
      },
      {
         "sub_categoryid": "2" ,
         "sub_categoryname": "Health2"
      },
      {
        "sub_categoryid": "3" ,
        "sub_categoryname": "Health3"
      }
     ]
   }
]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create separate entity for subcategory and add a one to many relation to the subcategory.

The managed object model will looks like following[image]

Then go to Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass.
You will get 4 files

```
SubCategory.swift
SubCategory+CoreDataProperties.swift
Category.swift
Category+CoreDataProperties.swift
```

In `Category.swift` add the following method

```
func addSubcategoryObject(sub: SubCategory) {
    sub.category = self
}
```

Then parse your data like follows

```
data = your data.....
let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary
if let categories = json["category"] as? [NSDictionary] {
    for category in categories {
        let categoryObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Category", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! Category
        categoryObject.category_name = category["category_name"] as? String
        categoryObject.id = NSNumber(integer: Int((category["id"] as? String)!)!)
        categoryObject.sub_category_count = NSNumber(integer: Int((category["sub_category_count"] as? String)!)!)

        if let subcateories = category["sub_category"] as? [NSDictionary] {
            for subCategory in subcateories {
                let subCategoryObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("SubCategory", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! SubCategory
                subCategoryObject.sub_categoryname = subCategory["sub_categoryname"] as? String
                subCategoryObject.sub_categoryid = NSNumber(integer: Int((subCategory["sub_categoryid"] as? String)!)!)
                categoryObject.addSubcategoryObject(subCategoryObject)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You should add an inverse relation **category** in `Subcategory` to `Category`

Comment: but how should I store this subcategories data?

Comment: you'll have an array of SubCategory in your Category model, so you have to create a SubCategory object for each subcategory you have in your dictionary

Comment: u mean to say I should take array of SubCategory object in category Model

Comment: bot array, you can simply add a relation in your model. then create managed objects for those entities. you can understand the use then

Comment: You can refer relations tutorial here http://www.raywenderlich.com/14742/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-how-to-work-with-relations-and-predicates  its in Objective C. Will update my answer in a while

Comment: its the inverse relation of category

Comment: categoryObject.addSubcategoryObject not access